# How to prove there is no set $S$ containing all sets equipotent to $A \neq \varnothing$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let  $A\neq\varnothing$; prove there is no set $S$ containing all sets equipotent to $A$.

My proof outline: Assume such a set $S$ exists. If I can show $\bigcup S$ (which is a set)  = "set of all sets", then I have derived a contradiction. But, how do I show that?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Every set is a member of some set equipotent to $A$.

Comment: @PeterKošinár: I have tried to show every set is a member of some set equipotent to A to no avail

Comment: Consider any set $X$. If $X\in A$, we are done (clearly, $A$ is equipotent to itself). If $X\not in A$, we can take any $y\in A$ and replace it by $X$ to obtain a set equipotent to $A$, which contains $X$.

Comment: @Douglas: Why did you change the $\varnothing$ to $\emptyset$?

Comment: I'll change it back; I shouldn't have changed it (my main purpose was to add a title). [Hmm... although, now that I look, it was `\emptyset` in the original version.]

Comment: @Douglas: Hm. It seems that you're right. I'm sorry, I didn't see that. Let's just keep it like for now... Sorry to have bothered you!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

If you already know that the collection of all sets is not a set, you can show that the collection $W=\{x\mid x\notin A\land x\neq\varnothing\}$ is not a set (how many sets are not in this collection?). Then you can find an injection from $W$ into $S$ by fixing $a\in A$ and considering $(A\setminus\{a\})\cup\{x\}$. What happens if $S$ was a set? Show that the collection of all sets, or even just $W$ is a set as well.