# If $A \neq \varnothing$, prove that there is no set containing all sets equipotent to $A$

Tags: set-theory

Help with this exercise ... please ... I tried to try it, but I can not ...

Let  $A\neq\varnothing$; prove there is no set $S$ containing all sets equipotent to $A$. (Suggestion: Show that $\bigcup S$ would be the class of all sets).

Comment: Please tell us what is the definition of equipotent, in your book.

Comment: The sets A and B are equipotent (they have the same cardinality or the same power) if there is a bijective function f with domain A and rank B. That's where I can not go forward, because the suggestion tells me "set class" .. I'm new to this, please help me ... a guideline ...

Comment: One more thing is $S$ the set containing all sets or the set containing all sets of cardinality |A|?

Comment: Actually: duplicate of [How to prove there is no set $S$ containing all sets equipotent to $A \neq \varnothing$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445986/how-to-prove-there-is-no-set-s-containing-all-sets-equipotent-to-a-neq-varn)

Answer (score 2):

The hint seems to assume that you already know that there is no set of all sets. It's also assumed that you know what $\bigcup S$ means.

So the suggestion is that you produce a proof of the form:

> Assume that $S=\{x : |x|=|A|\}$ exists. Then (bla bla bla bla) and therefore $\bigcup S$ would be the set of all sets. But there is no such thing, so we have reached a contradiction. Therefore there *does not* exist any $S$ that is $\{x:|x|=|A|\}$.

It's up to you to fill out the "bla bla bla bla" with an argument that for *every* set $y$ you would have $y\in \bigcup S$, or in other words, for every set $y$, there is *some* $x$ with $|x|=|A|$ and $y\in x$.

(A natural approach to this would be to divide into cases according to whether $y\in A$ or $y\notin A$).

Comment: Mmmmm... Could you use "equipotency" instead of "cardinality"?

Comment: @user433796: There is a variety of ways to write that $A$ and $B$ are equipotent. If $|A|=|B|$ is not the one that is used in your course, just use whatever symbol it is you do use.

Comment: Is it possible to demonstrate with functions?

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ contains all sets and $S$ is a set, then what is $S \cup \{S\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal S$ be the be the class of all sets. Then clearly $\mathcal S \supset \bigcup S$

To show the other containment. Let $P$ be a set in $\mathcal S$, but the set $P$ is a SET, thus it is in $\bigcup S$. This shows the double containment thus  $\mathcal S = \bigcup S$.

For the second part, I might be misreading it but I think you need to use Hausdorff maximal principle, and contradiction.